# How to optimize a Flutter website for deployment with flutter build web?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, deployment, web-hosting

I'm preparing to deploy my Flutter website built with Android Studio. I'd like to understand how to use the `flutter build web` command effectively. Here's what I want to know:

- What are the essential command-line options to prioritize performance in the production build?
- Are there any additional optimizations or build settings I should consider?

**Previous Research:**

I've read the official Flutter web documentation, but it doesn't provide in-depth performance optimization guidance for the build process.

Comment: What does "high quality in pixels" mean?  What performance metrics are you trying to meet?  Without stating your benchmarks you are asking for opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correctly optimize and set up a flutter web app for production refer to the [official Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf), which goes very deep on tips and to-dos when preparing for a deployment.

When you feel comfortable with the changes, prepare and deploy your app.
The Flutter documentation helps us deploy a web app and is really well written!

[Here is the link](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web)

Since you are asking for a "command" to run in the terminal:

as written in the documentation under the "Building the app for release" section:

> Build the app for deployment using the flutter build web command. You can also choose which renderer to use by using the --web-renderer option

So use the following command to build your app:

```
flutter build web
```